# Помогите исправить ошибки в коде

Tags: c, массивы, функции

//Поменять местами первый максимальный элемент массива А (60) и последний максимальный элемент массива В (85)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 60
#define M 85
void inmas(int*,int );
void swapmax1max2(int *,int,int);
void outmas(int*,int);
int main()
{
int a[N],b[M],i,j,max1=0,max2=0,n,m,temp;
printf("Заполните массив A[60]");
inmas(a,60);
printf("Заполните массив B[85]");
inmas(b,85);
printf("Измененный массив A[60]");
outmas(a,60);
printf("Измененный массив B[85]");
outmas(b,85);
swapmas(max1,max2);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
void inmas(int*x,int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
scanf("%d",x+1);
}
void outmas(int *x,int n)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d",*(x+i));
}

void swapmax1max2(int *a,int n)
{
int i,j,max1,max2;
max1=*x;
max2=*x;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
   if (*(x+i)>max1){
      max1=*(x+i);
     }
  }
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
   if (*(x+j)>max2){
      max2=*(x+j);
     }
  }

{
temp = max1;
max1 = max2;
max2 = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Не особо понятно что значит первый максимальный элемент и последний максимальный элемент. Пожалуйста, по-подробнее.

Comment: Не надо вандалировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если вы ищете первый максимальный, то да, должны записывать новый максимум только при условии "строго больше". Но если *последний* - то при условии "больше или равно".

Во-вторых, запоминать нужно не только сами значения, но и индексы, где они находятся в массивах, а затем обменивать не два переменные со значениями, а *два элемента массива*.

В-третьих, надо быть аккуратнее - ну что за... объявить

```
void swapmax1max2(int *,int,int);
```

определить

```
void swapmax1max2(int *a,int n)
```

а работать внутри с необъявленной переменной `x`?..

Ну и - в этой `swapmax1max2` работать нужно с обоими массивами, а не с одним - вам же нужно искать максимумы *в разных* массивах, и обменивать элементы из разных массивов.

Ну как, сможете в коде воплотить мои замечания, или полная безнадеги и - "дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что даже программа не пишется"? :)

**Update**

Как видно из вашего кода, полная безнадега.
Хочется верить в то, что вы разберете код, который я вам даю, и не будете лепить такие глупости, как вызов функции с передачей не аргументов, а типов - вот как вы тут начудили:

```
outmas(b,85);
swapmax1max2(int *,int );
system("pause");
```

Нате нормальный работающий код... Только это уже не помощь - это, к вашему стыду, сделанная вместо вас работа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 60
#define M 85

void inpmas(int*,int );
void swapmax1max2(int *,int,int*,int);
void outmas(int*,int);

int main()
{
    int a[N],b[M];
    printf("Заполните массив A\n");
    inpmas(a,N);
    printf("Заполните массив B\n");
    inpmas(b,M);

    swapmax1max2(a,N,b,M);

    printf("Измененный массив A:\n");
    outmas(a,N);
    printf("Измененный массив B:\n");
    outmas(b,M);
    system("pause");
}

void inpmas(int*x, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Введите элемент #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
}

void outmas(int *x,int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ",x[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

void swapmax1max2(int *a,int n, int*b, int m)
{
    int max1 = *a, idxa = 0;
    int max2 = *b, idxb = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] > max1)
            max1 = a[idxa = i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        if (b[i] >= max2)
            max2 = b[idxb = i];
    }
    int temp = a[idxa];
    a[idxa] = b[idxb];
    b[idxb] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Значит, не исправили...

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: `max1 = a[idxa = i];` - не надо так с новичками :)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов А по мне - только так и надо: препод начнет выяснять, что это - поневоле придется разбираться :)